# Is there a way to get the average of a column which the query is not grouped by

Tags: sql

I dont rly know how to explain my Problem, but i have a Query where i need to group by a column but on the other i need to get an avg of a column which is not grouped by.

My Code is like this:

```
Select SID,PID,Cost, AVG(COST)
from catalog
group by SID,PID
ORDER by SID
```

All Columns are in the same table.
What can i do to get the AVG(Cost) of PID?

My Question is related to an exam question which is the following: Find the SID's who charge more for some PID than the average cost of that PID.

The table has the columns SID, PID, COST. I cant upload pictures of the table because my account is new, so im sorry.

So my Problem was that i couldnt get the AVG of the PID, my next Problem because i already tried it with Partition is, that i dont know how the having clause has to look like. Do i need a sub-query for that?

Comment: You haven't specified which SQL engine you're using.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) You may also benefit from [this helpful article on what is considered necessary for an SQL question](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: Your problem doesn't make much sense - can you provide some sample input and output to show exactly what you're working with and what you're expecting?

Comment: Your code is fine if you remove Cost and execute this: `Select SID,PID, AVG(COST) from...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions to add an average to a row:

```
select SID, PID, Cost,
       avg(cost) over (partition by pid) as avg_cost_for_pid
from catalog
order by sid;
```